# Scheme: Can't seem to load file

Tags: scheme

Trying to load a scheme file from terminal.  I've created one called test.scm containing the following code:

```
(define (square x) (* x x))

(define (sum-of-squares x y) 
  (+ (square x) (square y))
)

(define (big-square x y z)
    (cond ( (and (< x y) (< x z)) (sum-of-squares y z) )
          ( (and (< y x) (< y z)) (sum-of-squares x z) )
          (else (sum-of-squares x y))
    )
)
```

and I run:

1) scheme (everything starts up fine on OS X)
2) load 'test.scm'

I get back:

```
;Value 13: #[compiled-procedure 13 ("load" #x2) #x1a #x1045a82c2]

1 ]=>
;Value: test.scm
```

3) `(sum-of-squares 3 4)`

I'm expecting 25 but instead I get:

;Unbound variable: sum-of-squares

Any idea what's going on here?  When I try:

```
(square 5)
```

I get back 25 as expected...

Comment: Which Scheme implementation are you using? Unless it handles `load` in a special way, you want `(load "test.scm")`. (I suspect that you're using the builtin `square`, not your own. You can verify this by renaming it.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have evaluated the symbol `load`. You got back `#[compiled-procedure 13 ("load" #x2) #x1a #x1045a82c2]` which says `load` is a procedure.

You'll get something similar if you evaluate any of the other standard procedures, like `+`, however if you want to use `+` you use parentheses and arguments like `(+ 2 3) ; ==> 5`.

If you want to use the procedure `load`you need to use parentheses:

```scm
(load "test.scm")
```